# How to extend Pod library class from my custom class

Tags: ios, cocoapods, cashapelayer

I am using a pod library called(**CCKit** - an example name) in my iOS project. Library give a set of **CCKCAShapeLayer** objects at some places. **CCKCAShapeLayer** is extended from **CAShapeLayer**.

In my project I have my own custom class of CAShapeLayer called **ACVShapeLayer**.

My question is how can I get **ACVShapeLayer** instances instead of **CCKCAShapeLayer** from CCKit.

Comment: Why would you do that.

Comment: I need some extra features in that shape layers which are not available in CCKCAShapeLayer. I can add a instance of ACVShapeLayer as a sublayer . But it will increase the layers amount in layer tree. Basically I don't want to add new layers and have extra features at the same time.

Comment: what you can do is this create a shapeLayer class inherited from CCKit and add your functionalities as well in it.

Comment: Yeah I can do that. But the layer instances I am getting from CCKit will still be in its type(CCKCAShapeLayer)